# VMWare Guest OS networking problems talking with Host OS over wireless

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

My setup is the following:

- VMWare Workstation 6.5
- Host OS - Vista Ultimate x64
- Guest OS - Vista Ultimate x64
- Notes - Both OS in same domain and
  using DHCP (and can talk to any machine on the network and over the internet fine)
- Other special Notes - this is a newer
  laptop and the network adapter
  supports IPV6
- Network Adapter - Bridged (with
  Replicate State checked)
- Guest Isolation - VMCI is checked to
  allow host communication
- The goal is to get both the Guest and
  Host to see eachother and the
  network.

I have tried the following with the following results (just pinging):

Disabled all network adapters on HostOS (except wireless) : 
This works intermittently from the HostOS to the GuestOS (dropped packets), and doesn't work at all from the GuestOS to the HostOS ... however I did notice something strange when I ping the GuestOS(by name) on the GuestOS ... it successfully pings with IPV6 ... when I ping the GuestOS(by name) from the HostOS it seemingly uses IPV4. I disabled IPV6 on both adapters (Guest and Host) and received similar results and the GuestOS ping to the GuestOS looks something like this :::::::1 but it states that it was a successful ping.

Tried everything I did above, however, over the regular ethernet adapter:
Works like a champ no problems. However that weird self ping on the GuestOS still returns IPV6 responses.

Tried NAT with similar results.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have one to test on, but I believe you can't really get bridging to work over wireless, you have to use NAT mode or similar.

However, someone on Vmware's community site suggested this trick:

If you use the Virtual Network Editor, Automatic Bridging tab, and turn off Automatic, then select the adaptor you do NOT want to use it will switch to the other. So you would select NOT to bridge the non-wireless card.

Comment: +1 - you can't bridge a wireless card right now with VMware.  NAT is the only easy way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble following exactly what you are trying to do, but :1 (with varying number of colons) is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1 on IPv4.

If you suspect the physical adapters in the host OS are giving you problems manually install the MS Loopback adapter and configure it with a static IP and see how you go with that.